# How to configure image size with gphoto2

Tags: lubuntu, camera

I'm using gphoto2 with Lubuntu on a acer Aspire One and a Nikon D70s, all old stuff, but still usefull. But i have a problem when i try to take a picture from command line, because all the pictures i take are 160x120 (seems to be thumbnails). The code i use is some variants of this:

```
gphoto2 --set-config "resolution=4" --no-keep -I 20 -F 3150 --capture-image-and-download --filename "%Y%m%d%H%M%S.nef"
```

I tried with `--set-config "resolution=RAW"` with and without single and double quotation marks but always i have an error:

```
*** Error ***
Property 'resolution' not found.
```

and `--set-config imagesize=4` but i have similar error:

```
*** Error ***
The property 'Image Size' / 0x5003 was not set (0x2007: PTP Incomplete Transfer)
```

The camera is set as NEF(raw) I don't know how to configure the Image Size. Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what all config options are present for Nikon D70 but I am using Nikon D90 (must be fairly same) and this is what I would suggest.

To get all the config options:

`gphoto2 --list-all-config`

The first error is pretty clear, there is no such config as `resolution`. I am guessing you want to change the image format, for that you must see all the available choices that you have for `imagequality`.

`gphoto2 --get-config imagequality`

Once you decide on an option (RAW = NEF) you can set that as the option by

`gphoto2 --set-config imagequality=<choice number>`

Finally, I guess you want to change the imagesize, I would advise checking the supported options by getting the `imagesize` config as mentioned above.

For more reference:

- `http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/ref-gphoto2-cli.html`
- `http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/FAQ.html`

Answer (score 0):

*Not an expert on gphoto2 but this is what I have experienced.*

**Quick Suggestion/Solution**

Try using `imagefrmat` or `imageformatsd` based on your use case instead of using `resolution` or `imagequality` like

```
gphoto2 --set-config imageformat=0 --set-config imageformatsd=0 --capture-image-and-download --filename "myfile.jpg"
```

or

```
gphoto2 --set-config imageformat=0 --set-config imageformatsd=0 --capture-image --filename "myfile.jpg"
```

**Explanation**

Yes every camera might have different/specific config keyword to be used. It depends on what your camera supports. Following explanation might help you identify yours.

**My Setup:**

- Raspberry Pi 2 B+ with octopi instance running over it.
- Canon 1100D (in some regions known as rebel t3 or t3i).

- *Failed attempt:*

  - With a basic google search I also ended up using `imagequality` as well as `resolution` as the config parameters like this

    ```
    gphoto2 --set-config imagequality=0 --capture-image --filename "myfile.jpg"
    ```

    or

    ```
    gphoto2 --set-config resolution=0 --capture-image --filename "myfile.jpg"
    ```
  - This ended up with the same result as yours

    ```
    you@yourpi:~ $ gphoto2 --set-config imagequality=0 --capture-image --filename "myfile.jpg" 

    *** Error ***
    imagequality not found in configuration tree.
    New file is in location /capt0000.jpg on the camera
    you@yourpi:~ $
    ```
- *Successful Attempt*

  - Call

    ```
    gphoto2 --list-all-config
    ```

    This shows you all the available configs for the particular camera attached. This also shows the options or variables that can be used to set something like 0 for fine quality in my camera / use case.

    For example in my camera to check battery level the config listed is

    ```
    gphoto2 --get-config batterylevel
    ```

    which is used to read battery level while those config which do not have readonly set to 1 means they can be changed, they can be configured like

    ```
    gphoto2 --set-config imageformat=0 --set-config shutterspeed=1 --capture-image
    ```

**Please note:** some settings are not allowed to be modified as the dial (mode selection) on camera is set to predefined modes. For example if you put camera in full automatic mode the sutterspeed option becomes readonly.

So the best practise is to keep camera in manual settings/mode unless you are sure you want auto mode but set the wait time for auto mode to complete its operation accordingly like focus etc.